# Are there studies showing that language study is more effective in a group than individually?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request

Often, it's claimed that in a group, you have people to practice verbal exercises with, as well as potential proofreaders and error-checkers to verify the grammar and spelling of your work. However, I've found nothing to the like on the Internet.

Are there any studies addressing the fact that it is often claimed that learning the same new language with two or three friends or family members can help you learn the language faster? I'm fine with referencing your own personal experience, but scientific references are preferred. (All members of the group are learning the same language, and all have the same native language).

Comment: What do you mean by effective? If you measure effectivity by the use of teacher's time, group learning will be more effective for certain.

Comment: An important aspect of learning a language in a group instead of alone, is that you will be able to get feedback in a group.

Comment: This question seems to pose a false dichotomy. One needn't choose between group or individual study, and in reality, rarely does a student do this! Most students mix both methodologies. Would it therefore make more sense to ask about the relative strengths and weaknesses of each method, rather than if one is "more effective"? I'd be fairly surprised to find if a study of this nature actually exists, as I suspect no researchers would be daft enough to think that such an artificial distinction was worthy of study.

Comment: @Flimzy That's exactly why I'm asking. Yes, students use both methodologies, but which should they spend more time in? Individual study or group study?

Comment: I still think you're asking the wrong question (in your comment). As a student, don't ask "Which should one spend more time on?" but "How should I use both methodologies for their greatest combined potential?"

Comment: If you're fine with answers with personal experience, do you think that asking for studies only (in the title) is at least unnecessary? See more about my answer in [Suggestion: Avoid asking yes-or-no questions](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/183/168)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Group learning helps you to learn language faster.**

I don't have any scientific references but I am mentioning my personal experience here as you said you are okay with personal experiences too.

We had a group learning experience when I was learning the English language. We had various activities such as debates, small dramas, word building games, some small competitions related to vocabulary amongst us.

I am pretty sure that I learned more in those 2 months of group study than an year of self learning I had before.

> Yes, students use both methodologies, but which should they spend more time in? Individual study or group study? <sub>from comments of OP</sub>

I believe that Group study should be given more importance.

> All members of the group are learning the same language, and all have the same native language

We were all learning English and Tamil was the native language for all of us.

Comment: Oh, I speak Tamil as well. Good answer!